# Rounding up to powers of 2 (with preprocessor constants)

Tags: c, macros

Using `unsigned int`s it's possible to round to a power of 2 like this:

```c
unsigned int power_of_2_max_u(unsigned int x)
{
    x -= 1;
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    x = x | (x >> 8);
    x = x | (x >>16);
    return x + 1;
}
```

or…

```c
int is_power_of_2_i(int n)
{
    return (n & (n - 1)) == 0;
}

int power_of_2_max_i(int n)
{
    if (is_power_of_2_i(n))
        return n;

    do {
        n = n & (n - 1);
    } while (!is_power_of_2_i(n));

    return n * 2;
}
```

However when the value is a constant, it should be possible to use the preprocessor to avoid having to calculate the value every time. e. g.:

```c
i = power_of_2_max_u(sizeof(SomeStruct));
```

This is a macro which is equivalent to `power_of_2_max_u`.

```c
#define POW2_CEIL(v) (1 + \
(((((((((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) | \
      (((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) >> 0x08)) | \
     ((((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) | \
      (((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) >> 0x08)) >> 0x04))) | \
   ((((((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) | \
      (((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) >> 0x08)) | \
     ((((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) | \
      (((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) >> 0x08)) >> 0x04))) >> 0x02))) | \
 ((((((((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) | \
      (((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) >> 0x08)) | \
     ((((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) | \
      (((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) >> 0x08)) >> 0x04))) | \
   ((((((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) | \
      (((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) >> 0x08)) | \
     ((((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) | \
      (((v) - 1) | (((v) - 1) >> 0x10) >> 0x08)) >> 0x04))) >> 0x02))) >> 0x01))))
```

Generated by this Python-3 script.

```py
import math
BITS = 32
data = (["(v - 1)"] +
        ["(v | (v >> 0x%02x))" % i
         for i in reversed([2 ** j
         for j in range(int(math.log2(BITS)))])])
macro = "1 + v"
for l in reversed(data):
    macro = macro.replace('v', '(%s)' % l)
print("#define POW2_CEIL(v)", macro)
```

Using [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) it can be made a little nicer, but this relies on a GCC extension.

```c
#define POW2_CEIL(x_) ({      \
    unsigned int x = x_; \
    x -= 1;              \
    x = x | (x >> 1);    \
    x = x | (x >> 2);    \
    x = x | (x >> 4);    \
    x = x | (x >> 8);    \
    x = x | (x >>16);    \
    x + 1; })
```

While this is a fairly ugly macro, I double checked and the compiler does reduce this correctly to a constant (as it should) so `unsigned int a = 8;` is exactly equivalent to `unsigned int a = POW2_CEIL(7);`,
however I was interested to know if there was a better way to do this (possibly not limited to an int range).

Comment: Well you are doing bitwise operations like `shiftRight` so No, you do need to use unsigneds , however the bitwise operation arithmetic are really fast I think you probably should stay with this ugly code :)

Comment: Though, note that with your first power_of_2_max_u() function body being available before use (make it static inline and place it in a header file), most optimizing compilers will optimize it to a constant - which you can verify by looking at the generated assembly.

Comment: What do you mean by "possibly not limited to an int range"? Every integer number (even numeric constants) that is handled by C code has some kind of range. If you want to work with larger numbers, just use `int_least64_t` or `uint_least64_t` as the type of the parameter in your function definition. Or cast `x` to said type inside the macro definition if you prefer that.

Answer (score 3):

> However when the value is a constant, it should be possible to use the preprocessor to avoid having to calculate the value every time.

Readability >>> performance. First of all, ask yourself the question" *"is this a real bottleneck in my code?"*

If the answer is "no", then don't do anything; move on without thinking about micro-"optimizing" your code prematurely.

Even if this is an important part of your code, consider that **your functions are pure.** Their return value only depends on their arguments, since they perform simple computations (a mapping, basically). **Chances are, any decent optimizing compiler will constant-fold your functions when called with expressions known at compile-time.**

For example, the following code…

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned power_of_2_max_u(unsigned x)
{
    x -= 1;
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    x = x | (x >> 8);
    x = x | (x >>16);
    return x + 1;
}

struct Foo {
    int x;
    char c;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    printf("%zu %u\n", sizeof(struct Foo), power_of_2_max_u(sizeof(struct Foo)));

    return 0;
}
```

…is translated to the following assembly by `clang -O2 -flto`:

```
/tmp/constfold:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000f50    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f51    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f54    leaq    0x37(%rip), %rdi  ## literal pool for: "%zu %u\n"
0000000100000f5b    movl    $0xc, %esi        ## *** sizeof(struct Foo) == 12
0000000100000f60    movl    $0x10, %edx       ## *** rounded up == 16
0000000100000f65    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f67    callq   0x100000f70       ## symbol stub for: _printf
0000000100000f6c    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f6e    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f6f    retq
```

So, **you didn't need to do *anything* for the compiler to constant-fold your function.**

Only consider re-writing your functions as one of the macros above (or using non-portable compiler intrinsics) if you can observe that they are **not** being constant-folded.

Comment: This is meta-correct because it is **not** the preprocessor that performs the perceived 'optimisation', as asked in the original question.  The preprocessor simply expands the macro in place in the source and the **compiler** does the constant-folding.

Comment: @MikeofSST Of course I am perfectly aware of that. It is possible (and was apparently not uncommon at some earlier point), though, that a compiler can be too dumb to constant-fold a function call (with so many assignments inside), while it is able to constant-fold an expression in which there's no call.

Comment: I upvoted.  My remark was to clarify why it is a better answer than simply another macro definition.  Sorry for any confusion.  :-)

Comment: @MikeofSST No problem whatsoever :) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Noting that a compiler can likely optimize this out is useful, but there are still cases when you need a value to be a constant (using compile-time-asserts for instance, or when used to define the size of a fixed size data-structure).

Answer (score 0):

How about using a nice compiler built-in (works in gcc and clang):

```
int msb = 31 - __builtin_clz(v);
int log2_value = v > (1U << msb) ? msb + 1 : msb;
```

or, for 64b case:

```
int msb = 63 - __builtin_clzl(v);
int log2_value = v > (1ULL << msb) ? msb + 1 : msb;
```

(v is an input variable).

Wrapping the above into a macro or c++ `constexpr` is left as exercise to a reader.

Using MSVC, a built-in, similar to `__builtin_clz` is called `_BitScanReverse` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).